# How to save the information in Telegram notification by python ? (possible?)

Tags: python, notifications, telegram, telegram-bot

I want when someone sends a message in Telegram, the information of the message is stored in the telegram bot or something else without seeing the other party's message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just want to know if it can be done or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to do what is known as "ghost mode" which means you read messages but they're not double-checked.

Before I answer your question, I should warn you that Telegram's founder is against such use (see https://twitter.com/durov/status/891227609706536960).

The fun fact is you don't have to do anything to avoid double-checking a message. In fact there is an extra step for that. Therefore, all you need to do is to read the message. You can do so in telethon as simple as this:

```
@app.on(events.NewMessage())
def read(event):
    print(event.message.message)
```

Comment: Can I have your Telegram?
I need more help.